# Saving outlook email attachment to disk to enable reading of file content by strings.exe or exiftool.exe safe?

Tags: outlook-addin, exiftool

I am using strings.exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings and

[exiftool.exe](https://exiftool.org)

to try and establish whether the outlook attachments are the file type that they are listed and just haven't changed their extension

Problem is that both of these tool expect a filepath which would force me to use `.SaveAsFile(string path)` on the mail item attachment object and save to disk to scan them before I delete them

**Is this a security risk?**

As far as I know I am not executing the file simply reading its metadata and therefore any malicious files should not be executed right?

I am using this wrapper to read the file from c# https://github.com/AerisG222/NExifTool

I have bitdefender installed on the machine and I know I have tried to save a test virus file and it immediately picked it up and deleted it

I have had a look at redemption and it has an option to return AsStream which would allow to use in memory but to scan with exiftools.exe and strings.exe they are both expecting a filepath

hoping to get answer before so-police comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be a security risk. The file is never executed.
More than that, OOM blocks certain attachment types (such as exe) - they are not even accessible in the `MailItem.Attachments` collection (unless you are using Redemption of course).

Comment: does the same apply to .zip files or other compression files if I read the content of them using ZipFile.OpenRead?